# Custom view is not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `MVC` model technique for my project. If I am writing code for `custom view` in `viewDidLoad` directly in `viewController` file then  `view` is appearing. But if I am creating another class for view then it is not showing label.

**Code:**

ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[homepagVar homeView:self.view]; /* homepagVar is the variable of homePage class and homeView is method of homePage class */

[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

**homePage Class:**

```
-(UIView*)homeView:(UIView*)Hview
{

    toplabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 18, Hview.frame.size.width,30)];

    toplabel.text=@"NexgHomes.com";
    toplabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    toplabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    toplabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"size:18];
    toplabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    [Hview addSubview:toplabel];
    return Hview;
}
```

**It is not showing label in this way. Why?**

Comment: you have to add subView in viewDidLoad as different class may have different self.view instance

Comment: My first guess is that the Label is clipped as it doesn't fit in the rectangle. Hmm you should replace self.view by Hview in your homeView method.

Comment: Shouldn't you add the subview to `Hview`, not self.view? Or set self.view=Hview (and by the way, by convention, your variable should be named `hView`).  Also, where do you set `homepagVar` ?

Comment: I have edited it? Please see my code again @Paulw11

Comment: It is still not working @Paulw11

Comment: Have you actually assigned an instance of your homepage class to `homePagVar`?  ie. it isn't nil?

Comment: try to call [super viewDidLoad] before calling homeView, and also, put a breakpoint in homeView and verify that the frame of Hview is not 0 for the width and the height.

Comment: I have not allocated  memory for `homePageVar`, That is why it is not coming. After allocating , It is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

  [super viewDidLoad];
  [homepagVar homeView:self.view]; 
  [self.view addSubview:homepagVar];

}
```

Comment: `homepagVar` is variable of  `HomePage` class not of `UIView` class. Thank you anyway. @lalit

Comment: I have not allocated memory for homePageVar, That is why it is not coming. After allocating , It is appearing. It was silly mistake by me. @lalit